# get top left coordinates of a modal (jquery kendo-ui)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, offset, getboundingclientrect

I have a straight forward draggable modal window via jquery kendu-ui.

My goal is to simply get the screen coordinates of the `top` `left` position of a modal, relative to the browser window... I am trying `offset` and `getBoundingClientRect()` methods, below is just an example of a few attempts, all attempts are constantly console logging `0`, `0`, .. what am I doing wrong here?

```
 let ktop = $(".k-window").offset().top;
 let ktlft = $(".k-window").offset().left;
 console.log(ktop + " " + ktlft);
```

---

```
 let ktl = document.querySelector('.k-window');
 let procoords = ktl.getBoundingClientRect();
```

---

```
 let ktl = document.querySelector('.k-window');
 let ktlTop = ktl.offsetTop;
 let ktlLeft = ktl.offsetLeft;
```

Comment: Is the `.k-window` element visible in the DOM when you try and read the values?

Comment: absolutely, I am testing in the browser as it is already even up... and I still cannot console any coordinates

Comment: Is it possible for you to show a working example in the question? One thing to note is that if there are multiple `.k-window` elements in the DOM then all three of your code examples will only ever look at the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo by default creates two `.k-window` elements, one is for draggable purpose, the other is for "physical" window. Your attempts always take the first one that is stack to the top 0 and left 0 with `visibility: visible`, but with `display: none`.

One of the options is to find `k-window` wrapper by your window id:

```
$('#my-window').closest('.k-window');
```

Example: [Get offset](https://dojo.telerik.com/UDICOqON)